# how to set opacity for Model3D in WPF?

Tags: wpf, 3d, opacity

Is there a way to set opacity for a Model3D in WPF, besides iterating through all it's materials and setting their brush's opacity?

Iterating through all its materials and setting their brush's opacity seems to work only part of the time.

Thanks